# Как пройтись по списку элементов DIVa "chatlist" Selenium PYTHON

Tags: python, html, парсер, selenium

Написал скрипт для перебора всех чатов внутри DIVa на сайте (сайт предоставить могу но там нужно логинится на специальный аккаунт, доступ к которому не могу публиковать для всех).

Все работает и перебор по созданому списку идет отлично НО. На сайте есть скрипт который подгружает в HTML максимум 30 чатов. Даже если скриллить вниз то те чаты что выше убираются и на их место стают новые, что то вроде переопределения переменных. Как можно сделать так что бы можно было пройтись по всем чатам вниз. Может как то список пересоздавать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вкладку network в dev-tools, скорее всего данные о чатах подгружаются через fetch, напишите свой запрос (или несколько последовательных) который отдаст все
данные о чатах, ну и думаю selenium для этого избыточен, я бы посмотрел в сторону requests